# Give an example of a Random Vector.

Tags: random-variables

I need to see a real-life example of a random vector using common and simple examples like dice, a deck of card, coin-toss, and so on (don't use complicated examples like [signal-noise](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-random-vector), roulette, poker, etc).

Give an example of a Random Vector.

.

**Note:** [here is an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbrVQNmmQ4s) which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: What they refer to as a "vector" is merely a tuple and does not need to satisfy any properties of vector spaces so I think the name is misleading.  That being said... take two or more of your favorite examples of random variables, $X,Y,\dots$.  Then $(X,Y,\dots)$ is a "random vector."

Comment: If you insist on having a concrete example using dice and such... throw six dice.  Let $X$ count the number of occurrences of $1$.  Let $Y$ count the sum of the dice.  Then $(X,Y)$ is a "random vector."

Comment: @JMoravitz, then, what is the difference between **joint r.v** and an **r.v vector**?